# Drawing line using mouse on html canvas is not drawing line on correct position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I am able to draw a line using mouse on html canvas at correct position. Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="InitThis();">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <div align="center">
        <canvas id=c width="500" height="200" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

function InitThis() {
    ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext("2d");
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');

    $('#c').mousedown(function (e) {
        mousePressed = true;
        Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, false);
    });

    $('#c').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, true);
        }
    });

    $('#c').mouseup(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
        $('#c').mouseleave(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
}

function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 9;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}
```

But when I included video and moved the canvas position in html, line is being drawn when I use mouse but not at correct position where I clicked the mouse. It is being drawn down well below the mouse position.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="InitThis();">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <div align="center">
        <video id=v controls loop autoplay muted>
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>-
        </video>
        <canvas id=c style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.css:**

```
#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 400;
    height: 300;
}

#v {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 400;
    height: 300;
}
```

index.js is same as the first program. Initially I thought it is happening because of video element. But even after removing video element also, same issue is happening. I was thinking because of position as 'absolute'. But I need the canvas and video elements at the same positions I mentioned in index.css. Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue.

**Note:** This is working fine when I test using codepen (https://codepen.io/adinakr/pen/OJymJNj). But when I try it directly on the browsers, the issue is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, putting `top: 0px;`, `bottom: 0px;`, `right: 0px;` and `left: 0px;` together doesn't make sense.
Second, I don't recommend using `width: 400px;` and `height: 300px;` with `<canvas>`, because they make it shrinking. So that's why it's being drawn in the incorrect position.
So instead, use the `width` and `height` attributes in the `<canvas>` element.
Here is an example:

```
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Here is your code:

```js
var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

function InitThis() {
    ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext("2d");
    
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');

    $('#c').mousedown(function (e) {
        mousePressed = true;
        //Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
        Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, false);
    });

    $('#c').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            //Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
            Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, true);
        }
    });

    $('#c').mouseup(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
     $('#c').mouseleave(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
}

function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 9;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}

function clearArea() {
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
```

```css
#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    //bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    //right: 0;
    //width: 400;
    //height: 300;
}

#v {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 400;
    height: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="InitThis();">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <div align="center">
        <video id=v controls loop autoplay muted>
          <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type=video/mp4>
        </video>
        <canvas id=c></canvas>
        <!--<br /><br />
        <button onclick="javascript:clearArea();return false;">Clear Area</button> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```